# Can't import MaterialComponents in class

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, material-design

every thing else is working fine but this materialComponents can not be imported anywhere in the project. I have tried-build the project, restart Xcode.

```
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'BitcoinTicker' do
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Alamofire' 
pod 'MaterialComponents'

end
```

[image]

Comment: I've installed this pod without any problems and `import MaterialComponents` works. Try to clean the project.

Comment: @VadimNikolaev tried but cant import only this pod.

Comment: make sure you build to prime the Xcode module cache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try re-installing pods using:

```
    pod deintegrate
```

```
    pod install
```

Clean and build the project.

Comment: May be you want to report this issue to owner.